# How to define a getter property, for an already defined JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, getter, javascript-objects

Consider this code:

```
// Creating an empty object, without inheriting (binding) to any prototype
var human = Object.create(null); 
human.firstName = 'Saeed';
human.lastName = 'Neamati';
```

Now, I want to add a `fullName` property to this object, which returns the `firstName + ' ' + lastName` of the object.

Using object literal notation, I can simply write a getter function this way:

```
var human = {  
   firstName: 'Saeed',
   lastName: 'Neamati',
   get fullName() {
       return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
   }   
}
```

But I can't figure out how to attach a getter property to an object, which is already built somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```
Object.defineProperty(<object>, <property-name>, <descriptor>);
```

Where `<descriptor>` can be something like:

```
// from the example:
{ value: 0x9f91102,   
  get: function() { return 0xdeadbeef; } }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Human = function(){
  human.firstName = 'Saeed';
  human.lastName = 'Neamati';
};

human.prototype.getFullName = function(){
  return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
}

var humanOne = new Human();
alert(humanOne.getFullName());
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks @Juljan. But what you wrote is not a **getter property**. It's a **method**.